# Плавное уменьшение и увеличение ImageButton

Tags: android, android-animation

Подскажите как через Scale сделать анимацию у ImageButton чтобы оно уменьшалось до определенного момента и тут же возвращалось к исходному размеру.

Пробовала так

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.1"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.1"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="100" />
</set>
```

но кнопка сильно уменьшается резко и плавно в исходное состояние возвращается, а я бы хотела чтобы оно немного уменьшилось плавно, и также плавно вернулось. Типа эффект нажатия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, на девайсе не проверял, должно сработать

```
<scale
   android:fromXScale="0.1"
   android:toXScale="1.0"
   android:fromYScale="0.1"
   android:toYScale="1.0"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:duration="500"
   android:repeatCount="1"
   android:repeatMode="reverse" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, переделала ваш код немного и добилась нужного эффекта

Comment: А что именно изменили?

Comment: Вместо fromXScale="0.1" написала 0.8 и убрала android:repeatCount и android:repeatMode

Comment: из-за этих атрибутов как мне кажется был эффект пульсации.

Comment: Ясно, полезненько.

Comment: спасибо еще раз.